# Two transaction accesing the same table concurrently

Tags: java, sql-server, concurrency, transactions

I have a method which is concurrently called. In that method I have a defined a transaction in which some `DELETE` operations and `SELECT` operations are happening on the parameter passed in the method. I try to invoke this method concurrently and pass different data at each instant. I am get an error:

> Error 1205 : Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction

The body of method looks like this:

```java
public void method(param){
  //transaction starts
  // delete operation on table 1
  // select operation on table 1
  // transaction is committed. 
}
```

Let there be Transaction T1 and T2

I think this deadlock condition should not occur because in this case row level locking would have been applied on the basis of parameter I passed in the method. If Transaction T2 one wants to delete other data then Transaction T1 should not hinder it from deleting it. What is happening is that one transaction is being rolled back since I am catching `SQLException` therefore only one record is successfully getting deleted. Can anyone figure out why this doesn't work?

Comment: Is it not acceptable here to use java's concurrency mechanisms? - `synchronized`

Comment: hi Erkan i am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @lynks : its not that i can use java's concurrency mechanisms the point is that this is a justifiable scenario both transactions should be executed successfully as they are not accessing same data in table, which isnt happening!!!

Comment: If the transaction isolation is high deadlock are very likely to occur. To understand what happens try to look at SQL Server monitor and identify the resource that causes the deadlock

Comment: Are you accessing the same instance of the class to hit the database?  @lynks - if he has two different instances, `synchronized` isn't going to do him any good, and this needs to be handled at the database layer anyways.  We're going to need to see both the `DELETE` and the `SELECT` statement, and try and figure out which of the two is causing the deadlock.  My _guess_ is that both the `DELETE`s are 'passing', but that the `SELECT` would actually be affected by both of them, and so has to wait for the other to be committed to run...  Maybe tell the DB to ignore locked rows?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: but the select also shouldn't cause deadlock because of different data involved. Well if there is a situation where i am deleting some data from table and at the same time if i am doing select different records from table which is different from the records i am deleting then the select operation should be successfully executed but that is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, depending on the indexes in use, some databases may use table level locks when you think they should be using row level locks.  so, step 1 is to verify that you are in fact using row level locks.

second, are you using any automatic cascading which could be affecting other tables when you delete?  and/or are there foreign key relationships involed.  missing indexes in this situation can also cause problems.

third, sometimes updates can affect more than 1 row due to how the indexes are handled.  some databases lock "chunks" of the index whenever there is an update (e.g. a row deletion).  it's possible that there are conflicts due to the locks on the indexes.

Comment: well the table from which i m trying to delete records is using primary keys of other tables as foreign key. Does that create a problem. There is no cascading logic involved here.

Comment: @Naman - are the foreign keys indexed?  i vaguely remember problems with oracle where if the foreign key fields weren't indexed, you'd get table level locks (or something like that).

Comment: @Naman - i realize, i'm just saying what type of problem i saw and where i saw it.  whether or not sql server has a similar problem is up to you to figure out (or someone else with more sql server knowledge than i).

Comment: i forgot to add one thing during these concurrent calls the transactions are created under same hibernate session only because we are reusing the session by picking it from thread local. Will that create a problem ????